# Google Web Fonts not working after Firefox 7 upgrade

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I have no idea why this is happening. I am following the standard tried and tested method of using google web fonts

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sunshiney' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style>
    h1{ font-family: 'Sunshiney', cursive; }
</style>

<h1>Hi there</h1>
```

This works in Safari, Chrome and IE but not FF7.

Has anyone come across this. I've also tried using the JS integration and the @import syntax and it is the same. I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue with Google Web Fonts. An internal configuration change broke serving of one of the headers needed for reliable operation in Firefox and IE9+. The fix is propagating now and it should be working soon.

Thanks for reporting the issue!

(I'm an engineer on the Google Web Fonts team, found this in a twitter search trying to investigate how deep the breakage went)

Answer (score 3):

I think its problem with google 
On my browser FF 7.01 is show Comics Sans

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sunshiney  => redirect to

themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/sunshiney/[...]3HZu7kw.woff

And response with no font data

but when type this adress in url bar i can save this font

so.
Just download this font and simple embennded to webpage

Will be faster

eq

```
====> 0,20second to download family=Sunshiney

     =====> 0,30 to download woff font
```

Comment: Yea. It works locally thanks for the suggestion. Not sure what is going on really

Answer (score 1):

There is currently an issue on Google's end with the Webfonts. It's odd because they were working just a few days ago, and I've seen them load up once or twice, but otherwise it's reverting to the fallback font.

Your best option is to download the file and manually embed it into your webpage using @font-face. There's a good article on that [at Six Revisions](http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/).

I hope Google gets it sorted soon.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps someone, I just had a problem with Google Web Fonts not rendering on a colleague's Mac, but working on other (similarly configured) Macs.  It was obviously something client side, and turned out to be the `browser.display.use_document_fonts` setting (see [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About%3aconfig_entries)).

To stop it happening, it's a case of going to Preferences .. Content .. Fonts & Colors .. Advanced and making sure "Allow pages to chose their own fonts, instead of my selections above" is checked.